# I'm trying to fetch data using multiple value when user select just one value from drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have this select drop down list

```
<select name="avalable" id="avalable">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="1">Spring</option>
          <option value="0">Fall</option>
        </select>
```

I post the value like this

```
 $avalablesemster= isset($_POST['avalable']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['avalable']) : '';
```

In the table I have the value sorted like

```
Fall=0
Spring=1
Both=2
```

what I need to do for example if user select Fall I need to fetch Fall and Both (0 AND 2) 
If the user select Spring I need to fetch Spring and Both (1 AND 2)

If the use select 'All'  I need to fetch Fall,Spring and Bothe (0 ,1,2)

I have tried to do this

```
$str='';
if($avalablesemster==''){
    $str=" ('0','1','2') ";
}
elseif ($avalablesemster=='0')
{
   $str=" ('0','2') ";
}elseif ($avalablesemster=='1')
{
 $str=" ('1','2') ";
}
```

I got this error now

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

This is my complete code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']) AND $_POST['Submit'] == 'Submit') {
    $coursneededdate = isset($_POST['needed']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['needed']) : '';
    $gradunder=isset($_POST['gradunder']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['gradunder']) : '';
    $avalablesemster= isset($_POST['avalable']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['avalable']) : '';

$str='';
if($avalablesemster==''){
    $str=" ('0','1','2') ";
}
elseif ($avalablesemster=='0')
{
   $str=" ('0','2') ";
}elseif ($avalablesemster=='1')
{
 $str=" ('1','2') ";
}

    $result2 ="SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  curriculumcourses NATURAL 
  JOIN courses 
 where semester_ava = '$str' 
  AND curriculum_id IN 
  (SELECT 
    curriculum_id 
  FROM
    curriculum 
  WHERE '".$coursneededdate."'
   BETWEEN startdate  AND enddate ";
if(!empty($gradunder)){
 $result2 .=" AND grad_under = '".$gradunder."'";
}
 $result2 .=") GROUP BY (course_id);";
```

***UPDATE***
@chris85 I have closed the sub query like this. Is this correct?

```
    $result2 ="SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  curriculumcourses NATURAL 
  JOIN courses 
 where semester_ava IN $str 
  AND curriculum_id IN 
  (SELECT 
    curriculum_id 
  FROM
    curriculum 
  WHERE '".$coursneededdate."'
   BETWEEN startdate  AND enddate ";
if(!empty($gradunder)){
 $result2 .=" AND grad_under = '".$gradunder."' GROUP BY (course_id)";
}
 $result2 .=")";
```

Now when I tested this code it will bring me all courses despite the condition in the sub query? Any help please?

Comment: It should be `WHERE semester_ava IN $str`.

Comment: If `$gradunder` is not empty you're not closing your subquery.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `$mysqli->query`?

Comment: Go it, it working now many thinks @barmar

Comment: Check the return value of `$mysqli->query`. If it's `false`, use `die($mysqli->error)` to see the MySQL error.

Comment: @barmar I just put IN, and got it to work. Thank you

Comment: I don't see how that could have fixed the error. Your code was valid syntax, it should just not find any matches.

Comment: @chris85 thank you, it worked when I put IN $str

Comment: You'll still have the issue I mentioned, you just must not have tested with that variable populated (or I'm misreading).

Comment: @barmar I'm sure there is match and got this"Trying to get property of non-object" before using IN (:

Comment: @chris85 I was having the issue with $avalablesemster not $gradunder I'm testing the query right now to make sure it is working as expected. Thank you (:

Comment: @chris85 you were right, It gives me falls data, I do not now why?

Comment: Maybe because I'm not closing the query @chris85?

Comment: GROUP BY appears nonsensical here, as does real_escape. See about mysqli's prepared statements. Also, is it a large data set?

Comment: Different Curriculums may have the same course, I need to bring one course only if it is exists in more the one curriclums that's why I'm using GROUP BY

Comment: @barmar $result3 = $mysqli->query($result2);

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
       ......

Comment: @chris85 can you please help in this one too? I would appreciated.

Comment: Thank you ALL it is fixed now.

Comment: Got it? Just need the closing `)` to close the sub-query in your conditional, like in your `else`.

Comment: It is working now as expected, thank you @chris85